# In each table check background color and validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with some row colored as green.Each row have a checkbox.
When I click submit button i need to validate that only green colored row whose checkboxes are not checked should be checked.
No other colored rows and just the green one(#47A347).
Below is my html.Can anyone help me getting the solution.

```
<form method="post" action="test2.html">
        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#47A347" class="rowb">
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" class="linebox"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#47A347" class="rowb">
                <td>Hello 1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="linebox"></td>
            </tr>
              <tr class="rowb">
                <td>Hello 2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            </form>
```

I have tried below jquery code.Though it works it fails sometimes.

```
 <script>
             jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn', function (event) 
            {
                var rv = true; 
                $(".rowb").each(function() 
                {                       
                if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)") 
                {
                 var ischk = 0;
                 var row = $(this);                        
                 if (row.find('input[class="linebox"]').is(':checked') ) 
                 {
                      ischk++;
                 }
                 if(ischk==0)
                {   
                    rv=false;
                }
                }                         
                });
                 if (!rv) 
                 { 
                     alert('Please check');
                     event.preventDefault(); 
                 }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're here to help, but you have to show some effort here

Comment: Ohh yes I have tried it

Comment: Could you please edit in what you have tried? It helps knowing what you have tried, otherwise somebody makes an answer, and you go "Oh sorry, I already tried that", and that wastes time :)

Comment: I have added the code i tried.

Comment: Has your question been resolved? If so, please mark the most suitable answer for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet. Should give you an alert for each green checkbox that has not been checked on click of the submit 'btn'. If there is a green row checkbox that has not been checked, the default submit action will be stopped.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('#btn').on('click', function(){  
    var i = 1;
    var error = false;
    $(".rowb").each(function() {  
      ischk = 0;
      if($(this).attr("bgcolor") == "#47A347") {                      
        if (!$(this).find('input.linebox').is(':checked') ) 
        {
          alert('Please check green checkbox #' + i);
          error = true;
        } 
        i++;
     }
    });
    if (error){
      event.preventDefault(); 
    }
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="test2.html">
        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#47A347" class="rowb">
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" class="linebox"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#47A347" class="rowb">
                <td>Hello 1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="linebox"></td>
            </tr>
              <tr class="rowb">
                <td>Hello 2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asserting in `background-color` try checking for `bgcolor` attribute.

```
//if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)") 
if( $(this).attr("bgcolor") == "#47A347" )
```

Here's the full refactored code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn', function (event)
            {
                var rv = true;
                $(".rowb").each(function()
                    {
                        if($(this).attr("bgcolor") == "#47A347")
                            {
                                if ( !$(this).find('.linebox').is(':checked') )
                                {
                                    rv = false;
                                    return false
                                }
                            }
                    }); 
             if (!rv)
             {
                 alert('Please check');
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  var data = {};
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $('[bgcolor="#47A347"]', form).each(function(){
    data[this.id] = $(this).find('input').val();
  })
});
```

Note: you didn't provide name attribute for inputs. With name attribute provided you can use jQuery's [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to gather form data automatically. To filter out unneeded fields you can temporarily set them to disabled state.